# Foreign Key not working: Error code 1005, SQL state HY000: Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables I have created and I'm adding the foreign key constraint after the fact.

The two tables are defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_ad_id` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `login_id` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `personal_config` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal_config (
    config_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    last_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    configuration TEXT(25600) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (config_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE personal_config ADD CONSTRAINT personal_config_fk_user FOREIGN KEY 
(config_id) REFERENCES user(personal_config);
```

And I keep getting the same error but can't figure it out. I've searched all the related threads to this.

Comment: Where do you get the error, after the first CREATE TABLE or the second?

Comment: Note that your `ALTER TABLE` seems backward. Since `config_id` is the auto_increment value, `user` should have a FK to personal_config, not the other way around.

Comment: After the second. The tables are created fine, its just the alter table that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ALTER TABLE` statement is backward. Since `personal_config.config_id` is an auto_increment primary key, the foreign key should be defined in the `users` table against `personal_config`, not in `personal_config` against the `users` table.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT user_fk_personal_config 
   FOREIGN KEY (personal_config)
   REFERENCES personal_config(config_id);
```

Comment: Just needed a second pair of eyes. Ok, so that makes sense and that fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Your FK `config_id` can't be an autoincrement field, that doesn't make much sense right?  That field reflects a value in the foreign table, it cannot be set arbitrarily in the local table.

I think this is what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT personal_config_fk_user FOREIGN KEY (personal_config) REFERENCES personal_config(config_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set your user table field personal_config is primary key then it is possible to execute

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal_config (
    config_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    last_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    configuration TEXT(25600) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (config_id), FOREIGN KEY 
(config_id) REFERENCES user(personal_config)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```